# How to turn off the scrolling down of WebBrowser control in Windows Phone 7.5

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control, windows-phone-7.8

I have a problem with `WebBrowser` control in Windows Phone 7.5 SDK (I didn't tried WP8).
Is there any possibility of turning off scrolling down whole page below "point 0" of vertical offset?

If you scroll page down you will see the white bar (example image).

The same story when you see bottom of the page, you can scroll even lower than this point and see white bar below.

IMAGE -> http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/281/68p8.png

Comment: In the future consider uploading images with stackoverflow 'Image' option (above edit box).

Comment: Yeah I did, but I needed points which I didn't have at that moment :)